# Number of hours per day when the database is running

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the calculator, I can select the number of hours per day when the database is running.
But when creating Cloud SQL, there is no option to select the number of hours.
How can I indicate the number of hours?

Answer (score 0):

The number of hours that you select in the pricing calculator correspond to the "Number of hours per day the database instance will be available for client connections". Therefore, this is not something you can set.

At this point your billing will vary depending on the usage of the instance and the number of hours that the instance will be available.